# Stream a video from Azure-Storage by using node.js '@azure/storage-blob' package

Tags: node.js, azure, express, video-streaming, azure-storage

The code below allows the streaming of a video from Azure-Storage by using node.js **'azure-storage'** package.

I want to achieve the same goal, but by using **'@azure/storage-blob'** package.

```js
.....
app.get("/video", (req, res) => {

    const videoPath = req.query.path;
    
    const blobService = createBlobService();

    const containerName = "videos";

    blobService.getBlobProperties(containerName, videoPath, (err, properties) => { 
        if (err) {
            console.error(`Error occurred getting properties for video ${containerName}/${videoPath}.`);
            console.error(err && err.stack || err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        // Writes HTTP headers to the response.

        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Length": properties.contentLength,
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
        });

        // Streams the video from Azure storage to the response.

        blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, videoPath, res, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Error occurred getting video ${containerName}/${videoPath} to stream.`);
                console.error(err && err.stack || err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`.....`);
});
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok,I find a solution ...

```js
app.get("/video", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
            AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
        );

        const containerName = 'videos';
        const blobName = req.query.path;

        // Get a reference to a container
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

        // Get a block blob client
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

        console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');

        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);

        downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody.pipe(res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});
```