# Stream a video from azure blob storage using node js

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage

I want to stream a video that is stored on azure blob storage. Front-end i am using react.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

On workaround try with following solutions

**Solution 1:** [**Azure Media Services**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/): enable you to build media applications using low-latency live streaming, batch encoding, content-protection/DRM, and deliver streaming content to millions of viewers on any device.

**Azure Media Services** is a cloud-based platform that enables you to build solutions that achieve broadcast-quality video streaming, enhance accessibility and distribution, analyze content, and much more.

For more details Refer this document how to connect to the Azure Media Services v3 node.js SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/configure-connect-nodejs-howto

Use the [Azure Media client library for JavaScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-mediaservices?activeTab=readme) with npm.

The uploaded video are stored as an `Assest` file if the files are uploaded using **Azure Media Services SDK.** which will make it easier to stream video to different devices.

To stream or download an asset, you first need to "publish" it by creating a locator. Locators provide access to files contained in the asset.

Once you create the locators, you can build the URLs that are used to stream or download your files.

**Note : you're uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage? If that's the case, instead of uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage, my suggestion would be to upload your videos using the Azure Media Services SDK**

**Solution 2:** try with this code  allows the **streaming of a video from Azure Storage by using node.js `@azure/storage-blob` package**.

```
 app.get("/video", async (req, res) => {
    
        try {
            // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
            const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
                AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
            );
    
            const containerName = 'videos';
            const blobName = req.query.path;
    
            // Get a reference to a container
            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    
            // Get a block blob client
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    
            console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');
    
            const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
    
            downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody.pipe(res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
    
    });
```

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615268/stream-a-video-from-azure-storage-by-using-node-js-azure-storage-blob-package):

Comment: Thank you for the reply
I have tried above solution but it does not work.

Comment: can you please try with **azuremediaservices**

Comment: awesome. it works. great job.

Comment: Can you share an example of how to stream media from blob storage using the azure media services sdk?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/arm-mediaservices/?view=azure-node-latest